# bash scripting: parallel for loops

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am writing a bash script to loop through 2 identical directory trees in order to do run diffs on matching files. I just need to know what is correct syntax to setup 2 loops that will run in parallel. I'd also like to iterated through directories recursively, so if there's an additional step to accomplish that, can you mention it?

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES1=/path/to/one
FILES2=/path/to/two
for f1 in $FILES1; f2 in $FILES2
do
  echo "Processing $f1 $f2 file..."
done
```

Comment: Do you actually want to process the first file from $FILES1 with the first from $FILES2, then second with second, and so on, or each file from $FILES1 with each from $FILES2 (i.e. a cross product)?

Comment: What's wrong with `diff -Naur /path/to/one /path/to/two`?

Comment: Paulo, I want the former: first with first, second with second, etc.

Comment: @ted and you are sure they are always ordered the same way?

Comment: jamessan, you solved my problem the best possible way, a one-liner. Why didn't you post it as an answer? I'll leave the question as it is b/c the loop question may be useful for others.

Comment: @paulo no i can't be sure they'll be ordered the same way.

Comment: @jamessan: Could you please post this as an answer (with some added text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

diff already has the builtin functionality to run recursively against directories.  You can run `diff -Naur /path/to/one /path/to/two`.

- `-N` will show the diff for new files, instead of just saying it exists in the second path
- `-a` treats all files as text, so you may or may not need this.
- `-u` uses the common unified diff format
- `-r` is the important, in this case, recursive flag

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that the files will be in the same order in the two directories.

Do it like this:

```
FILES1=/path/to/one
FILES2=/path/to/two
for f1 in $FILES1/*
do
  f2=$FILES2/`basename f1`
  # ...
done
```

And if you need to do it recursively:

```
cd $FILES1
for f1 in `find`; do
  f2=$FILES2/$f1
  # ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to nest the for loops, i.e.

```
   for f in $FILES1 ; do
      for f2 in $FILES2 ; do
         if [ ${f##*/} = ${f2##*/} ]; then
             diff $f $f2
             break
         fi
      done
  done
```

to iterate thru recursive dirs, you could rely on `find` to return a list of files for processing

```
 PATH1=/path/to/one
 PATH2=/path/to/two

 for f in $(find $PATH1 -print ) ; do
    for f2 in $(find $PATH2 -print ) ; do
       if [ ${f##*/} = ${f2##*/} ]; then
           diff $f $f2
           break
       fi
    done
done
```

Sorry I don't have a way to test this right now, the `${f##*/}` may not be exactly right. The intention is to create just the basename of a file (I guess you could use that too, `$(basename $f )` at the expense of an 2 processes for each.

Both of these are very expensive processes, checking lots of non-matching filename pairs. The break inside loop2 helps a little.

An alternate solution is to rely on one path to create the driver list and then use the supplied names to generate alternate relative paths, i.e.

```
for f in $FILES1 ; do
   f2=../two/$f{##*/}
   if [ -f ${f2} ] ; the
       diff $f $f2
   else
       printf "no alternate file found in ../two for f=${f}"
   fi
done
```

If need be, you can duplicate that loop and reverse the location of f2 and f to check the 'other-side' of your system.

I hope this helps.